# No feature to install packages using cyclic.sh

Tags: pip, cyclic

I have been developing a telegram bot using telethon in cyclic.sh .
I do not find any feature to use pip or terminal. Please help me. I need to install telethon, tqdm

I checked everywhere for the method but I was unable to find.